# Matlab function block Slows down Simulink simulation drastically

Tags: matlab, simulink, cdma

I am trying to add a matlab function block to a simulink model available in all matlab installations (commcdma2000). Adding a matlab function block slows down the simulation very drastically. I am using the standard malab function block instead of the interpreted MATLAB Function block because it is supposed to be faster. Also all that I do in the matlab function block is to assign the input to the output so there is no complex computation. I would like to add more complex logic within this block as part of my project and hence I pose this question.

Comment: Ofcourse it will slow down your computation time! That makes sense totalle, and that will happen. Avoid it if you are worried about computational time, or have a coffee while you simulate. If you are doing real time application Matlab will tell you if your code can be computed in the time steps given or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ander. My problem is, I would like to add some complex logic to the existing simulink model(commcdma2000). For this, the only option I can think of is to use a matlab function  block. But adding this makes the simulation so slow, it would never complete.

Comment: It will complete for sure. What do you mean "so slow"? Approximately how much time?

Comment: Hi Ander, thanks again for your reply. If I add even a simple matlab function block, which just assigns the input to the output, to the simulink model (commcdma2000) it completely stalls. I can e-mail you the simulink model with and without the matlab function block if you like. This problem is specific to the commcdma2000 model as it is very complex.